# What are the ways to display contents in a listed way in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How contents can be displayed properly in listed way in wp7 using C#?
ListBox can be used.But is there any other way.?

Comment: What's the problem with the listbox? It's highly customizable via Templates

Comment: the bottom most contents in listbox are not visible.

Comment: What do you mean not visible? Can you show the code/xaml that you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ScrollViewer, StackPanel

Comment: What is the difference between them and listbox?

Comment: A ScrollViewer is essentially the same, just works a bit differently with some different features, a StackPanel is basically a ListBox which does move/scroll

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for alternate list controls to use? I'd recommend taking a look at the LongListSelector control.

There are many good articles, but for WP7 specifically this one is great:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api